# Replace multiple sentences between 2 expressions in multiple files Notepad ++

Tags: regex, search, replace, notepad++

I have 58K files where I need to find this expression

```
()">A Random sentence.</A></P>
```

and i need to replace `A Random Sentence` by nothing.

I was trying on Notepad++ something like

```
Find What: ()">[[:alnum:][:punct:][:space:]]</A></P>

Replace: <empty>
```

Not even gettng results from the search...
Waiting for some feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to find 
`(\(\)">).*(<\/A><\/P>)`
 and replace it with
`$1\<empty\>$2`

The idea is to save left part and right part, placing essential parts in brackets ().
The ".*" means every character in between.
In replace statement we call $1 and $2 to access saved parts.

Comment: All of your answers we correct and helped a lot. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

Find: `(?<=\(\)">)A Random sentence.(?=<\/A><\/P>)`
Replace: `<empty>`

If `A Random sentence.` is not the actual sentence you can replace the find with:

```
(?<=\(\)">).*?(?=<\/A><\/P>)
```

Answer (score 0):

You also can try :

`(?<=\(\)">)[a-z \.-]+(?=</A></P>)`

here `[a-z \.-]` you put everything what you want to search
Also parenthesis in Notepad++ should be mark with `\`